# Give value to variable with clickable text

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

I would like to give the user the choice to choose between 'yes' or 'no' as answer on a given question. If the user for example clicks 'yes' i would like to give a variable thats called, let's say; $value the value 'yes' and vice versa if user clicks 'no'.

The problem is I don't know how to make a text string clickable and to only give the variable a value when the string is clicked.

My thought was to do something like this but as I have come to understand this probably isn't the way to do it?

```
<h1><a href="yes.php" onclick="<?php global $value; $value='YES'; ?>">YES</a>
<a href="yes.php" onclick="<?php global $value; $value='NO'; ?>">NO</a></h1>

<?php
    global $value;
    $answer=getDbInfo('Answer');

    if($value==$answer){
        echo 'Correct';
    }else{echo 'Incorrect';}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: This happens 100% on the client ans has ZERO to do with PHP - so please show an HTML/JS block of code.

Comment: You can't pass stuff back to PHP from an onclick function, by that time it's way too late!

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but the thing is I'm out of ideas for how to solve what I'm trying to do, forget about the onclick function, wich is the way to go?

Comment: You'll need ajax to pass stuff back to the server, but you'll have to explain the general idea of what you're trying to do, and maybe someone will post an alternative.

Comment: Okey so heres what Im rying to accomplish: The site gets a random question from the database, its then up to the user to guess whether the answer to that question is either yes or no. When the user clicks for example yes i would like to compare their answer to the correct answer o the question, which I got stored as a value in the same database table as I get the question from, and send a response like "correct answer" or "incorrect answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple suggestion is to use `GET` method like;

Name your file as `myfile.php`

```
<h1><a href="myfile.php?option=yes">YES</a>
<a href="myfile.php?option=no">NO</a></h1>

<?php
    $value = $_GET["option"];
    $answer=getDbInfo('Answer');

    if($value==$answer){
        echo 'Correct';
    }else{echo 'Incorrect';}
?>
```